# Terraform local variable not working with my "or" operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have terraform module with files:
main.tf
variables.tf

Within the variables I have defined:

```
variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "The environment the module is being deployed to, e.g: Test, Integrate or Production"
}
locals {
  scale_in_protection = var.environment == "production" || "integrate" ? "true" : "false"
}
```

I get this error:

```
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
╷
│ Error: Invalid operand
│
│   on ..\..\modules\jitsi\variables.tf line 99, in locals:
│   99:   scale_in_protection = var.environment == "production" || "integrate" ? "true" : "false"
│
│ Unsuitable value for right operand: a bool is required.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my own problem:

```
scale_in_protection = contains(["production", "integrate"], var.environment)  ? "true" : "false"
```

Turns out the || is only for variables not strings thus you need to use contains.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/contains.html

Answer (score 0):

Your [conditional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html) is not valid. It's missing the comparison of `var.environment` and `"integrate"`. Here's the fixed version:

```
variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "The environment the module is being deployed to, e.g: Test, Integrate or Production"
}

locals {
  scale_in_protection = var.environment == "production" || var.environment == "integrate" ? "true" : "false"
}
```